# How can I cache Android NDK in my Github Actions workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to cache the Android NDK in my Github Actions workflow. The reason is that I require a specific version of the NDK and CMake which aren't pre-installed on MacOS runners.

I tried to use the following workflow job to achieve this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:

    - name: Cache NDK
      id: cache-primes
      uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ${{ env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME }}
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-ndk-${{ hashFiles(env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME) }}

    - name: Install NDK
      run: echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "ndk;21.0.6113669" "cmake;3.10.2.4988404"
```

The problem with this is that the `env` context doesn't contain the `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` variable. So this means `build.steps.with.path` evaluates empty.

The regular environment variable is present and prints the correct path if I debug using the following step:

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
    - name: Debug print ANDROID_NDK_HOME
      run: echo $ANDROID_NDK_HOME
```

But the regular environment variable can only be used in shell scripts and not in `build.steps.with` as far as I understand.

Answer (score 6):

```
  - name: Prepare NDK dir for caching ( workaround for https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1337 )
    run: |
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk
      sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk
      sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk
  - name: NDK Cache
    id: ndk-cache
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk
      key: ndk-cache-21.0.6113669-v2
  - name: Install NDK
    if: steps.ndk-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
    run: echo "y" | sudo /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.0.6113669"
```

Here is a config I use in my project.

Couple of note:

- You need to create ndk directory and change permission to workaround https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1337
- Make sure
  you use proper `id` (ndk-cache in example above) in if statement so
  you can actually use cache

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're using an NDK version that is pre-installed with Github Actions runners, then you no longer need to worry about caching your NDK :)

Find the runners list here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-software

Example runner list:
https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md
For the Ubuntu 22.04 runner, it comes with three NDKs pre-installed

- 23.2.8568313
- 24.0.8215888
- 25.2.9519653 (default)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily specify the NDK installation directory to be cached.

```
- name: Cache (NDK)
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: ${ANDROID_HOME}/ndk/21.0.6113669
    key: ndk-cache


- name: Install NDK
  run: echo "y" | sudo ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install 'ndk;21.0.6113669'
```

Comment: just copying this into my workflow didn't work out of the box. NDK is installed again.

Comment: The cache is kinda buggy, i run the same CI script several times and the cache fails sometimes.

Comment: Are you sure that it ever worked for you?. Even if that were the case, the way this is written, NDK would ALWAYS be installed. You're not skipping the step of installing it when the cache is available (there's a syntax for that in github workflow files).

Comment: @Lukas1 I'm new to github actions but I think you have to check if cache was hit or not?
https://github.com/actions/cache#example-workflow

Comment: @Kazuki yes, that is correct. Thing is, it didn't really work using that syntax either for me when I wrote this comment. I have experimented with it but found no way to make the cache work and avoid installing NDK again and again.

Comment: @Lukas1 you wanna share part of your config somewhere? yesterday I added cache for my github actions and cache actually worked.

Comment: For your reference here is my code:

      - name: NDK Cache
        id: ndk-cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${ANDROID_HOME}/ndk/21.0.6113669
          key: ndk-cache-21.0.6113669
      - name: Install NDK
        if: steps.ndk-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: echo "y" | sudo /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.0.6113669"

Comment: @Kazuki yes, it works. I think you can post it as answer and hopefully it gets accepted. Because it is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: @Lukas1 actually my previous comment doesn't work (It won't cache correct folder because you cannot use env variable as path of cache action). I updated my solution above https://stackoverflow.com/a/63163680/1019366 just FYI. Also if you can upvote my answer that would be great.

Comment: in my own workflow I use `echo "y" | sudo ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install 'ndk;21.0.6113669'` also to install, it works for me, I don't need to create other folders.